# How can I find out whether the U.S. State Department will be providing staff to accept passport applications at my swearing-in ceremony?

Tags: usa, citizenship, passport, paperwork

I [read](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/is-true-i-can-us-passport-naturalization-oath-ceremony.html):

> You will not receive a U.S. passport on the day of your swearing-in ceremony. But in some places, if you plan ahead and also leave yourself some time at the end of the ceremony to stand in a long line, you might be able to apply for one. Find out whether the U.S. State Department will be providing staff to accept passport applications at your swearing-in ceremony.

How can I find out whether the U.S. State Department will be providing staff to accept passport applications at my swearing-in ceremony?

Comment: I don't think they advertise this ahead of time, but from what I gathered *large* ceremonies close to a passport office location (e.g.: NYC, Bay Area or Seattle) have much higher chance of them showing up.

Comment: @littleadv got it, makes sense, thanks!

Comment: You can make an appointment for passport application at a post office. The appointment can be for later the same day as your swearing-in ceremony, and you can then apply for the passport right afterwards.

Comment: @Aganju You *may* make an appointment. Whether you *can* is an entirely different question. By the time the ceremony is scheduled, the USPS appointments are usually all filled. In my area I had about a month notice before the ceremony and all the appointments at all the USPS offices within driving distance were filled for 3-4 months ahead.

Comment: @littleadv  [When applying for a new US passport at a Passport Acceptance Facility, can I go to any Passport Acceptance Facility or does it have to be nearby?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24074/164)