# When applying for a new US passport at a Passport Acceptance Facility, can I go to any Passport Acceptance Facility or does it have to be nearby?

Tags: usa, citizenship, passport

I wonder whether, when applying for a new US passport at a [Passport Acceptance Facility](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/how-apply/where-to-apply.html) (e.g., some [USPS](https://www.usps.com/international/passports.htm) or county clerk locations) via Passport Application Form DS-11, I can go to any Passport Acceptance Facility or does it have to near my domicile (e.g., in the same state or USCIS district).

Comment: Once you're a US citizen USCIS no longer has anything to do with you. At most you'll need them if you need to reissue your naturalization certificate. Once you're a US citizen, immigration enforcement does no longer apply to you and USCIS, ICE, immigration judges, and any other agency involved in dealing with foreigners no longer have anything to do with you. Similarly, state boundaries are meaningless when it comes to the Federal government (although some of the Federal district boundaries follow state boundaries occasionally, and state boundaries and US boundaries overlap for border states).

Comment: @littleadv thanks, great to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to any facility.

The actual passport issuance in the US is centralized and all the passports are issued by the State Department (as opposed to other countries where you may see "Issued at city X"). The Federal government doesn't care where you live. Notice that the address field on DS-11 is for *mailing* address. They ask for your residence address (on page 2) if it differs from mailing, but it is not a criteria for passport issuance.